# Active Processes running except the current process

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

If i write `ps -ef`, then it returns all the processes running currently. If i type `ps -ef | grep xxx`, then it returns all the processes running with substring `xxx`. but `ps -ef | grep xxx` is also a current process, so it returns `grep xxx` in the list too.

I just want to eliminate `grep xxx` from the list.

Can anyone help me with this.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
pgrep -fl xxx
```

Another solution

```
ps -ef | grep '[x]xx'
```

this is a simple regex trick to avoid repetition

`pgrep` is packaged in `procps`, on Debian :

```
$ LANG=C apt-cache show procps 
Package: procps
Priority: important
Section: admin
Installed-Size: 760
Maintainer: Craig Small <csmall@debian.org>
Replaces: bsdutils (<< 2.9x-1), watch
Provides: watch
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.3.4), libncurses5 (>= 5.7+20100313), libncursesw5 (>= 5.7+20100313), lsb-base (>= 3.0-10), initscripts
Recommends: psmisc
Conflicts: libproc-dev (<< 1:1.2.6-2), pgrep (<< 3.3-5), procps-nonfree, w-bassman (<< 1.0-3), watch
Size: 249178
Description: /proc file system utilities
 This package provides command line and full screen utilities for browsing
 procfs, a "pseudo" file system dynamically generated by the kernel to
 provide information about the status of entries in its process table
 (such as whether the process is running, stopped, or a "zombie").
 .
 It contains free, kill, pkill, pgrep, pmap, ps, pwdx, skill, slabtop,
 snice, sysctl, tload, top, uptime, vmstat, w, and watch.
Homepage: http://procps.sf.net/
Tag: admin::monitoring, interface::commandline, interface::text-mode, role::program, scope::utility, uitoolkit::ncurses, use::monitor, works-with::software:running
```

Comment: Same think @the same time. I answered 5 minutes before you and I had this snippet in the pipe to add.

Comment: Yes, since I was answering at that time I know.  I'm sure that you have other snippets in the pipe.  Good luck!

Comment: ps -ef | grep '[x]xx' works fine in solaris,hp and linux. But ps -ef | pgrep -fl xxx returns "broken pipe" error in hp-ux.

Comment: I never wrote `ps -ef | pgrep -fl xxx`; it's `pgrep -fl xxx` directly, that's all the magic.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of saying

```
ps -ef | grep xxx
```

say

```
ps -ef | grep [x]xx
```

and you wouldn't see `grep xxx` in the output.  (Essentially put the first character of the desired word as a character class `[]`.)